# Inheriting assigned properties from a mix-in

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to use a mix-in class to add properties to a model.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Taggable(object):
    tag_list = db.StringListProperty()

    def attach_tag(self, tag):
        self.tag_list.append(tag)
        self.put()

    def remove_tag(self, tag):
        self.tag_list.pop(self.tag_list.index(tag))
        self.put()

class Post(db.Model, Taggable):
    title = db.TextProperty()
```

This is just an example, no need to chew my ear off about bad practices or something.

Currently, I have something similar to this, except I have to put `tag_list = db.StringListProperty()` outside of the mix-in (errors otherwise), this is messy code, and I would like to avoid that.

Simply, how can I assign properties (such as `tag_list`) to a model from within a mix-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should not Taggable be based on db.Model instead of object?

Comment: Should it? I don't want `Taggable` to be an entity kind, I just want to inherit functionality from it.

Comment: Yes. Also it would then be a direct inheritance instead of a mix-in.

Comment: @Noah. I'm pretty sure it won't be an entity kind unless you instantiate a Taggable directly.  You can use it as a virtual class.

Comment: Just to be precise the datastore doesn't create the entity kind until the put is executed.  And the kind that is created corresponds to the inherited class (Post).

Comment: `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases: Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases Model, Taggable`

Comment: @Noah Reverse the order of the superclasses - (Taggable, db.Model) and it should work fine. It's necessary for the 'mixin' to inherit db.Model, because db.Model has a metaclass that does various magic to make the properties work.